# "Launch screens may not have triggered segues. LaunchScreen.storyboard"?

Tags: xcode

> Launch screens may not have triggered segues. LaunchScreen.storyboard

What does it mean? I am using Xcode and I am trying to do a segues.

Answer (score 12):

You cannot perform segues inside a launch screen story board.

`LaunhScreen.storyboard` files are static and cannot run codes, segues or other forms of animation. You should implement you UI inside `Main.storyboard` or another storyboard set as your main storyboard.

P.S.: [Using LaunchScreen storyboards](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/using-a-launch-screen-storyboard.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can't have segues to LaunchScreen.storyboard. Try to play with Main.storyboard.

> LaunchScreen.storyboard

is for splash screen.

> Main.storyboard

for adding scenes and more.

Comment: Can you, and if yes, how can you have two views in the launch storyboard!?